# Possible bug in Eclipse DDMS emulator control?

Tags: android, eclipse

I've just upgraded to Eclipse 3.6. I saved Eclipse 3.5 and made a copy of the original workspace.

I now notice an error in my GPS/mapping application which worked fine in 3.5, when I send a location from the DDMS perspective using the emulator control tab. I have a standard listener:

onLocationChanged(Location location){...}

If I break on the first line of this, having sent the lat/lon pair of 53.5/-3.0, then the mLatitude/mLongitude in the location argument have changed to 53.508833/-3.005000 (6 dec places only shown).
If I repeat with Eclipse 3.5 operating on the original project in its original workspace, then it's exactly right down to the smallest decimal place. It's exactly the same code in both workspaces.

The Android SDK is 2.2 in both and the target is Google APIs level 7.

Would you say this is a bug in the Eclipse 3.6 or the SDK or the plugin?

I don't think it can be an error on my part, but I'd be happy to be proved wrong. 0.005 of a degree may not sound much but it's 0.3 nautical mile on a great circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android recommends not using eclipse 3.6 with the ADT plugin. From [Eclipse ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

> ```
> Caution: There are known issues with the ADT plugin running with
> ```
>
> Eclipse 3.6. Please stay on 3.5 until
>   further notice.

So I wouldn't be surprised if there was a bug with either.

Comment: Thanks, I do remember seeing that but thought the main issues were context assist or not starting at all. I thought I'd been lucky. It's a shame as my 3.6 installation is a lot cleaner than the 3.5

Comment: I have tried with both Eclipse 3.5 and 3.6 now, but I get the same error in both. See [Emulator receives wrong GPS coordinates when playing KML in DDMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298019/emulator-receives-wrong-gps-coordinates-when-playing-kml-in-ddms)