# Bug in Eclipse Emulator DDMS?

Tags: android

I originally asked this question as a possible bug in Eclipse Helios :
[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738526/possible-bug-in-eclipse-ddms-emulator-control)

I accepted that it was bug in Helios but I now find that I'm now getting the same error under Eclipse 3.5

When I send a location from the DDMS perspective using the emulator control tab. I have a standard listener:

onLocationChanged(Location location){...}

If I break on the first line of this, having sent the lat/lon pair of 53.5/-3.0 from the DDMS tab, then the mLatitude/mLongitude in the location argument have changed to 53.508833/-3.005000 (6 dec places only shown).

The Android SDK is 2.2 in both and the target is Google APIs level 7.
Does anybody else experience this or could offer a possible explanation? (It amounts to quite a big error in terms of metres on the map.)

Comment: I have the same issue: [Emulator receives wrong GPS coordinates when playing KML in DDMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298019/emulator-receives-wrong-gps-coordinates-when-playing-kml-in-ddms)

Answer (score 0):

Yes!!! I have the same issue.

I also have Eclipse Helios, but not sure if this is a Helios issue, since I can start the Emulator from the command line, and send coords using "geo fix" command and get the same problem.

Could be an issue with new versions of Android SDK. I have used previous Android SDK and Eclipse Europa on a PC with no problem. Recently (Oct 2010) I bought a Mac, so I had to install new Eclipse and new Android SDK.

So I'm testing my app, the same one that works fine when testing on the PC, and I'm using the same GPX file that I always use to send coords to the app. And sure enough I get the weird issue you show above with extra numbers after the decimal point added in. Same thing if I use geo fix from command line.

Also, definitely not an App issue. I can open Google Maps in Emulator and send geo fix coords and then use My Location feature in Google maps and it centers on the wrong coords.

So I'm guessing a problem with Emulator in new versions of Android SDK.